# How can I dynamically change a textview using a spinner object?

Tags: java, android, textview, spinner

I want to have a spinner object that can change the text below it to something different whenever the user chooses a different option. 
I have tried implementing it like this:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int pos, long id) {
    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this); 
    LinearLayout lay = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.infoLayout);

    switch((int)id){

        case 0:
            String hours = "Office Hours:\n\tSummer: 9:00am - 10:00pm\n\tFall: 10:00am - 7:00pm";
            tv1.setText(hours);
            tv1.setPadding(0, 40, 0, 0);
            tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tv1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 35);
            tv1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            lay.addView(tv1);

            break;
        case 1:
            String products = "Wood - $8/bag (kindling and fuel wood available)\n" +
                    "Ice - $2.75/bag (crushed and on occasion blocks)";
            tv1.setText(products);
            tv1.setPadding(0, 40, 0, 0);
            tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tv1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25);
            tv1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            lay.addView(tv1);

            break;
        }
```

But the code I have only adds the new text to the bottom. I understand that this is because no removal method has been implemented, this is because nothing I tried worked and I thought this would be better than code that crashes every-time in hopes to get multiple opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the layout xml file, set an id for the `TextView`. Then make it an instance variable and change its text, instead of creating a new one every time.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    TextView textView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int pos, long id) {

        switch(pos){
          case 0:
            String hours = "Office Hours:\n\tSummer: 9:00am - 10:00pm\n\tFall: 10:00am - 7:00pm";
            textView.setText(hours);
            textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 35);

            break;
          case 1:
            String products = "Wood - $8/bag (kindling and fuel wood available)\n" +
                    "Ice - $2.75/bag (crushed and on occasion blocks)";
            textView.setText(products);
            textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25);

            break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you select an item you create a new TextView and add it to LinearLayout

```
TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
```

Declare `tv1` as instance variable and initialize it in `onCreate`.

Same for LinearLayout. No need to intialize it everytime you select an item. Also add the textview to Linearlayout once instead of doing it everytime. Change the text only.

Also change to `switch(pos)` instead of `switch(id)`

Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{

    Spinner spinner;
    String[] array;
    TextView tv1;
    LinearLayout ll;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country_arrays);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        tv1= new TextView(this);
        tv1.setText("Nothing selected");
        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
        ll.addView(tv1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          switch(arg2){

            case 0:
                String hours = "Office Hours:\n\tSummer: 9:00am - 10:00pm\n\tFall: 10:00am - 7:00pm";
                tv1.setText(hours);
                tv1.setPadding(0, 40, 0, 0);
                tv1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                tv1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 35);
                tv1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


                break;
            case 1:
                String products = "Wood - $8/bag (kindling and fuel wood available)\n" +
                        "Ice - $2.75/bag (crushed and on occasion blocks)";
                tv1.setText(products);
                tv1.setPadding(0, 40, 0, 0);
                tv1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                tv1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25);
                tv1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                break;
             default : tv1.setText("Defalut");   
            }
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the input! Both answers have helped very much!

Comment: @user3053529 glad to help. but you wanted to create textview programmaticaly and add it to linearlayout is it not?

Comment: That was my original intention but ultimately the selected answer implemented it more efficiently than I had expected, this is why I left the question "general" as to promote a range of possible answers.

Comment: @user3053529 how did you decide that was efficient?. Also this is wrong `switch((int)id){`. need to use  pos which is the index. Anyway left to you to decide.